# Python class inheritance - how to have inheritance from a previous inheritance?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a class like this.

```
 from flask.views import MethodView
 class FirstClass(MethodView):
```

I have another class like this.

```
 class SecondClass(FirstClass):

     def post(self):
         logging.info(self.request.body)
```

I was expecting that the SecondClass would inherit [MethodView](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.views.MethodView) Class. But it is not inheriting it. The MethodView will call the "post" def when there is a POST call, but it is not executing the "post" function. What should I do to have the SecondClass inherit MethodView class?

I was hoping to ***avoid*** (due to complexity in code)

```
 class SecondClass(FirstClass, MethodView):

     def post(self):
         logging.info(self.request.body)
```

When I do the above the MethodView kicks in to execute the "post" function when there is a POST call.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "it is not inheriting it"? `issubclass(SecondClass, MethodView) == True`, no?

Comment: Just clarified my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. SecondClass is indirect son of MethodView. SecondClass has all public method and members that MethodView has, because all these things are inherited through FirstClass.

Answer (score 1):

SecondClass's post method is overriding the post method of MethodView.

To assess MethodView's post method inside SecondClass's post method use the super() function

```
class SecondClass(FirstClass, MethodView):

     def post(self):
         logging.info(self.request.body)
         super(SecondClass, self).post()
```

[More here on the super function](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/super/working-python-super-function)